# JDBC Connection inside a Java UDF takes too long Teradata

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata, user-defined-functions

I have written a UDF that receives a string as its only argument, which is format. The UDF generates a code based on the format. After generating this, I'm inserting this code into the database using JDBC.

If the insertion query gets executed successfully, I return the code from function. If not, I regenerate the code (code is generated using few random numbers and few random characters).

The problem is the JDBC connection takes 1 sec to make the connection to Teradata Database from inside the UDF.

I have a table customers_email table with 7 million rows in it.

When I run following query, it is taking the whole day.

```
select myUDF('Win#!'),email_addres
from customer_email;
```

If I remove all the database JDBC interactions the result is really fast.

Comment: Please post the definition of your UDF.